# How to initialize a Task<List<string>> parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to write a unit test for function but I need to initiate some variables before testing it.

The function that I need to test has a parameter `Task<List<string>> list`

I want to initiate this variable.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Task<List<string>> list = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I've found my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want Task with empty List of string, you could call [Task.FromResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
Task<List<string>> list = Task.FromResult(new List<string>());
```